# AWS CloudWatchのログの確認について

Tags: aws, aws-cloudwatch

CloudWatchでEC2上で動いているnginxのエラーログを確認したいです。

[Nginx のアクセスログとエラーログを CloudWatch に送信する](https://enomotodev.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/19/214144)

上記リンク先を参考に進めたのですがnginx関連のロググループが追加されません。
どうかお力添えをよろしくお願いします。

**/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

CloudWatch現在のロググループ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

/var/log/awslogs.log に何らかエラーが記録されていると思われます。例えばリンク先にある「IAM ロールにポリシーをアタッチする」が実行できていないのではないでしょうか。当たり前ですがアクセス権がなければログを書き込むことができません。

なお、リンク先で紹介されているawslogsは非推奨です。[ドキュメント](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html)では

> 古いエージェントは Python 2.7、3.0、および 3.3 を必要とします。現在の EC2 インスタンスはこれらのバージョンの Python を使用しておらず、これらのバージョンは非推奨になって、パッチが適用されなくなっているため、**統合 CloudWatch エージェントに移行することを強くお勧めします。**

とされています。